# Python - How to make multiple GET requests at once

Tags: python, multithreading, python-requests, request

i'm currently working on a website scanner for local networks and i need to run multiple requests at once, i've tried using threads for that but it giving me exceptions and the program is crashing, it works fine if i have only a few URLs, here is my current code:

```
import requests
import ipaddress
import sys
import time
import threading
import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings()

ip_list = []
vulnerable_ip_list = []

if len(sys.argv) < 3:
    print("Missing argument...")
    exit()

def initialize_ip_list():
    for ip in ipaddress.IPv4Network(unicode(sys.argv[1])):
        ip_list.append(str(ip))
    
    print("IP List initialized, please wait for the program to finish.")
    
def initialize_threads():
    if len(ip_list) < int(sys.argv[2]):
        print("More threads than ips, limiting threads to " + str(len(ip_list)))
        for i in range(len(ip_list)):
            t1=threading.Thread(target=scan_ip)
            t1.start()
    else:
        for i in range(int(sys.argv[2])):
            t1=threading.Thread(target=scan_ip)
            t1.start()

def scan_ip():
    ip = ip_list.pop(0)
    try:
        host = "http://" + str(ip) + "/testurl/"
        r = requests.get(host, verify=False, timeout=5)
        status_code = r.status_code
        body = r.text
    
        if 'vulnerable test' in body.lower():
            print('Found Vulnerable URL: ' + host)
            with open("output.txt", "a") as txt_file:
                txt_file.write(ip + "\n")
    except:
        pass
    
    time.sleep(0.1)
    if len(ip_list) > 0:
        scan_ip()

initialize_ip_list()
initialize_threads()
```

Also here's the error i have:

```
Exception in thread Thread-27:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "scanner.py", line 50, in scan_ip
    scan_ip()
```

Thank you for anyone who's willing to help me.

Comment: Try ThreadPoolExecutor

Comment: You need a Thread-safe data structure to store IP addresses, otherwise stuff get messy. Try a [Queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html). Signal handling makes sure that at a certain time only one thread can access it's data.

Comment: Additionally to @nagyl comment, you could `ip_list.pop(0)` in `initialize_threads` and pass the ip as argument to the function. Which does not necessarily need a queue.

Comment: I will try to use ThreadPoolExecutor as mentioned by @Elazar, i will be back with the results in a few moments

Comment: ThreadPoolExecutor seems to fix the problems for now, thank you everyone who helped !

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing this problem:

- I firstly solved it by using a ThreadPoolExecutor as @Elazar mentioned in the answers, but it was giving me a memory leak as i was processing millions of data

What i did to solve this:

- i used another package that does the same but without the memory leak called BoundedPoolExecutor that can be found in here https://github.com/mowshon/bounded_pool_executor